# Gitlab coordinator waits 5 minutes after job finished by runner - How to diagnose

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a current (13.5.1-ee) Kubernetes deployed Gitlab which has recently developed an unusual and obstructive behaviour:

After a job finishes (either successfully or with a failure), and this is reported by the runner (as confirmed by the local log), the coordinator waits for 5 minutes to report the status via the UI and start the next job.

This behaviour does not depend on the:

- type of executor. It occurs with the `docker` and `kubernetes` executor.
- size of artifacts (for test cases there are none)
- size of logs (for test cases they are 5 lines long)
- image being used (for test cases it is busybox)
- script (for tests it is empty)
- network quality (for tests I have activated feature flags that this)

It feels that the coordinator is attempting a call to another system and times out.

Has anyone seen this before? Does anyone have a means to diagnose?

Comment: how you resolved this? I am also facing the same issue, it takes 5 min to give a success/fail status.

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/272578#note_435908465) affecting Azure.